# Faster way to use Pi camera module with OpenCV C++

Tags: raspbian, camera, opencv, image

I learnt that The pi camera module does not work the same as the USB camera and `VideoCapture cap(0)` doesn't work with pi camera module. I am using [this](http://github.com/samarth-robo/RPi-OpenCV) wrapper to get frames from pi camera module to use them with OpenCV. Unfortunately, frame rate is too slow for my work because of the wrapper.

Is there faster way to get frames from pi camera module to use them with OpenCV C++ ?

How do you use pi camera module with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `sudo moprobe bcm2835-v4l2`, and then try your code with the (0) as the Device ID, if it did not work try another ID.
if you are using the code for image processing(face detection , face recognition etc.) then you have to deal with delays and little frame per second .

good luck